# Making trigger in SQL Server 2014 with details given below:

Tags: database, triggers, sql-server-2014

Write a trigger which do not insert invalid `no_of_chapters` in `Publication` table. `No_of_chapters` of all authors of a specific book must be less than or equal to `total_chapters` of a book.

My attempt:

```
ALTER TRIGGER INS_STOP 
ON Publication 
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AID INT =(SELECT aid from Author)
    DECLARE @BID INT =(SELECT bid from Book) 
    DECLARE @N_O_C INT
    DECLARE @T_C INT =(Select total_chapters from Book)
    if(@N_O_C <= @T_C)
    BEGIN
         PRINT 'Invalid Number of Chapters' 
    END
END
```

Now the reason for this question how to check the value of `No_of_chapters` in trigger and how to give it when the user try to insert in table.

Database (`Author` table):

[image]

Database (`Book` table):

[image]

Inserted Data in `Author` and `Book` Table:

[image]

Database (`Publication` table):

[image]

Both `aid` and `bid` in `Publication` Table are foreign keys.

Comment: I doubt your tables `Book` and `Author` only ever have 1 row. Also, why do you not reference the `Inserted`  object here? You don't even reference the table the trigger is on.

Comment: ALso: what are the structures of the `Author`, `Book` and `Publication` tables, and what do their relationships look like?

Comment: @marc_s I have the updated the question and you can check their relationship now.

Comment: @Larnu Yes both of tables have only have one row in it and how to reference the inserted object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger has several fundamental flaws:

- You never reference the `Inserted` pseudo table - therefore, everytime something is inserted into `Publication`, you deal with the whole `Author` and `Book` tables - they won't stay at just one row each! Reference `Inserted` to get only those rows that were **actually** inserted into `Publication` !
- Your selects seems to indicate you assume a trigger is fired once per row being inserted - and that's **just NOT the case** in SQL Server. The `Inserted` pseudo table can (and **will!**) contain multiple rows - you need to handle those properly, in a set-based fashion

Now here, I don't see how `Author` is relevant at all - it's just about not inserting a publication with more chapters than the book allows.

You need to write your trigger something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER INS_STOP 
ON Publication 
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    -- check to see if any of the publications in the "Inserted" 
    -- pseudo table has more chapters than the reference "Book" allows
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM Inserted i
               INNER JOIN dbo.Book b ON i.bid = b.bid
               WHERE i.no_chapters > b.total_chapters)
    BEGIN
        THROW 71007, 'At least one publication contains more chapters than allowed by the book', 1;  
    END;
END
```

Check out the T-SQL official documentation on the `THROW` command - you can define the error number (here: 71007), message, and state (here: 1) as needed - see the official docs for details.